# Overriding the arguments sent to python decorator of an instance method

Tags: python, overriding, decorator

I have a method in a class which is decorated with a decorator that takes arguments. Something like this:

```
class SomeClass():
    @dec(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    def some_func(farg1, farg2, farg3):
        ....
        ...
```

Decorator is something like this

```
def dec(*data):
    def _api(func):
        func.__arguments_sent__ = data

        def internal_func(func, *args, **kwargs):
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return response

        return decorator.decorator(internal_fun, func)
    return _api
```

I'm trying to modify arg3 (sent in the decorator like this - @dec(arg1, arg2, arg3)) of some created instance of "SomeClass". how can I achieve this without changing my source code and re-creating this instance again?

I have a backdoor process which can modify this instance. I'm looking for the easiest way to achieve this modification.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how this would be called, and what would happen.  Would `arg3` be the name of the attribute of `SomeClass` that gets changed? How do you determine the value to change it to?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: I've some mapping between the arguments passed to the decorator and the function. The definition of my decorator is long and it checks whether the relation holds. arg3 is some static values like '5' etc, not related to dynamically changing instance of SomeClass. 
In simple words my arg3 is '5' in the code and I want to change it to '4' without re-creating my instance method. Thank you.

Comment: Decorator params are evaluated while parsing the class, which is way earlier than you are able to create a instance, so once you have instances forget about changing them. You should provide that argument from a class variable or instance variable instead of as an argument to the decorator

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to modify an object bound by the closure, but that has some caveats:

1. You won't be able to change that reference to point to a new object
2. All instances of the class share method definitions, and so they share the bound closure variables

Here's an example

```
import inspect

def deco(**data):
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print(data)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return outer

class A:
    @deco(a=1, b=2, c=3)
    def f(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.f()  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = A()
b.f()  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
inspect.getclosurevars(a.f).nonlocals['data']['a'] = 3
a.f()  # {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b.f()  # {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

There's almost certainly a much cleaner solution to the problem you're actually trying to solve that doesn't involve modifying method definitions after the fact.